# Hudson/SVN job configuration

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I am working on a project that is built in a modular way.  When the branch is checked out it, there are folders for each module.  I would like to setup a hudson job for each module to build each module individually, but I cannot figure out how to have one workspace for all the jobs and have each hudson job only check for changes for its respective module within the common workspace without triggering an update of the whole workspace.  Is this even possible what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Each job needs it's own workspace. everything else asks for trouble. If you have a shared workspace, you might need to synchronize the jobs so that they don't interfere with each other. That can be trickier than you expect.